# jQuery DataTables extensions cause errors

Tags: jquery, datatables

[image]

I am using the DataTables and the filter works just fine without any extensions,

- jquery.dataTables.min.js
- jquery.dataTables.min.css

but as soon as I add the buttons & select sources in the html,

JS

- jquery.dataTables.min.js
- dataTables.select.min.js
- dataTables.buttons.min.js

CSS

- jquery.dataTables.min.css
- select.dataTables.min.css
- buttons.dataTables.min.css

the filter starts to cause errors. Any idea why this might be happening?

The table setup in my page.js:

```
var table = $('#screen-table').DataTable({
            paging: false,
            scrollY: 400,
            data: result,

            // {"product":"Wide Skyscraper (Web Banner)","advertising_space":" CMT Whitelabel VECCI:Itinerary","application":"Check My Trip ",
            // "screen_code":"297","channel":"Websites","channel_type":"B2C","white_label":"VECI"}
            columns: [
                    { data: 'channel_type' },
                    { data: 'channel' },
                    { data: 'application' },
                    { data: 'advertising_space' },
                    { data: 'product' },
                    { data: 'screen_code' }
                ],
            rowCallback: function( row, data ) {
                if ( $.inArray(data.DT_RowId, selected) !== -1 ) {
                    $(row).addClass('selected');
                }
            },
            bInfo: false,

        });
```

---

EDIT: with non-min.js files, here is the error callstack

[image]

Comment: Are you using the latest DataTables 1.10.8, since Butons and Select requires 1.10.8?

Answer (score 1):

"ha" is a minified function name. If you swap for the non-minified files, you'll see the proper function that is called before it is defined.

I'd expect that the underlying cause is that you are missing a dependency or that you have loaded the files in the wrong order.

Comment: thanks for the answer. ha is related to highcharts i think, which is another problem. As for the other error, i tried changing the order but no joy.. any other ideas? i think i might be missing a dependency.

Comment: The error looks to be in the callback - this bit looks fishy  "$.inArray(data.DT_RowId, selected)" so put a breakpoint on it and evaluate in console at runtime?